# issue with predict with glmnetUtils

Tags: r, glmnet

trying to use the `glmnetUtils` package from GitHub for formula interface to glmnet but predict is not estimating enough values

```
library(nycflights13) # from GitHub
library(modelr)
library(dplyr)
library(glmnet)
library(glmnetUtils)
library(purrr)


fitfun=function(dF){
  cv.glmnet(arr_delay~distance+air_time+dep_time,data=dF)
}
gnetr2=function(model,datavals){
  yvar=all.vars(formula(model)[[2]])
  print(paste('y variable:',yvar))
  print('observations')
  print(str(as.data.frame(datavals)[[yvar]]))
  print('predictions')
  print(str(predict(object=model,newdata=datavals)))
  stats::cor(stats::predict(object=model, newdata=datavals), as.data.frame(datavals)[[yvar]], use='complete.obs')^2
}


flights %>% 
  group_by(carrier) %>% 
  do({
    crossv_mc(.,4) %>% 
      mutate(mdl=map(train,fitfun),
             r2=map2_dbl(mdl,test,gnetr2))
  })
```

the output from **gnetr2()**:

```
[1] "y variable: arr_delay"
[1] "observations"
 num [1:3693] -33 -6 47 4 15 -5 45 16 0 NA ...
NULL
[1] "predictions"
 num [1:3476, 1] 8.22 21.75 24.31 -7.96 -7.27 ...
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  ..$ : chr [1:3476] "1" "2" "3" "4" ...
  ..$ : chr "1"
NULL
Error: incompatible dimensions
```

any ideas what's going on? your help is much appreciated!

Comment: @Hack-R purrr.  sorry, edited it in.

Comment: Thanks for picking up on this. I'll push an update to glmnetUtils to allow NA handling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an issue with the underlying glmnet package, but there's no reason that it can't be handled in glmnetUtils. I've just [pushed an update](https://github.com/hong-revo/glmnetUtils) that should let you use the `na.action` argument with the `predict` method for formula-based calls.

- Setting `na.action=na.pass` (the default) will pad out the predictions to include NAs for rows with missing values
- `na.action=na.omit` or `na.exclude` will drop these rows

Note that the missingness of a given row may change depending on how much regularisation is done: if the NAs are for variables that get dropped from the model, then the row will be counted as being a complete case.

Also took the opportunity to fix a bug where the LHS of the formula contains an expression.

Give it a go with `install_github("Hong-Revo/glmnetUtils")` and tell me if anything breaks.

Comment: the default for `predict.glm` is  `na.action = na.pass`, which drops observations with NA. Shouldn't `na.exclude` pad the predictions?

Comment: You've got it backwards: `na.pass` keeps rows, and `na.exclude` drops rows. In general `predict.lm` and `glm` are complicated, but the behaviour I've got there should match the most common case where you leave the defaults unchanged when fitting the model, and specify newdata when predicting.

Comment: i guess i don't understand the semantics of predict.cv.glmnet. The new version works fine by default. if na.action=na.exclude then the same error occurs. I thought the default of predict() was na.pass hence the confusion. Thanks for the update!

Comment: Right, if your data has NAs, and you want to predict on it,  then just leave everything set to the default.

Comment: Also, the default for `predict.lm` and `glm` IS na.pass.

Comment: and predict.cv.glmnet uses predict.glm under the hood, correct?

Comment: No. The implementation has nothing to do with lm or glm.

Comment: ah, therein lies my misunderstanding. Thanks!

Comment: If this has left you confused about how predict.lm and glm handle NAs, just experiment with them a little. You should find that na.pass, na.omit and na.exclude all work the way I describe above. (You might also want to see what happens with and without a newdata argument.)

Answer (score 0):

Turns out its happening because there are NA in the predictor variables so `predict()` results in a shorter vector since `na.action=na.exclude`.

Normally a solution would be to use `predict(object,newdata,na.action=na.pass)` but `predict.cv.glmnet` [does not accept](http://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/glmnet/versions/2.0-5/topics/predict.cv.glmnet?) other arguments to `predict`.

Therefore the solution is to filter for complete cases before beginning

`flights=flights %>% filter(complete.cases(.))`